# C add some words after name file

Tags: c, pointers

```
void compressione(FILE* iDizionario, FILE* posizioneCorrente, FILE* iCorrispondenza, char* argv) {
    char* nomeFile;
    nomeFile = (char*)malloc( (3+strlen(argv))*sizeof(char) );
    strcpy(nomeFile, argv);
    nomeFile[strlen(argv)+1] = '.';
    nomeFile[strlen(argv)+2] = 'g';
    nomeFile[strlen(argv)+3] = 'f';
    ...
```

Simple:
argv is a pointer to char it points to a char array "input.txt"

```
char* nomeFile
```

take a space on the heap memory of the same size of argv pointers but with 3 more bytes.
after that i make a copy from argv to nomeFile so now both have input.txt 
now (because nomeFile pointer has 3 bytes more) in these 3 bytes i would like to put '.', 'g' and 'f' char.
so my idea is: i go exactly in the end of the name file+1 and i add the first char, same logic for the other two.
but doesnt happen anyting... in the debug mode the nomeFile pointer has the same string.

Comment: Do you have an off-by-one error (don't do +1 for the first addition)? The array starts at 0 and strlen()+1 points after the terminating nul char.

Comment: Yep, you have to start at `nomeFile[strlen(argv)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not leaving space for the trailing 0 byte in `nomeFile`. This byte isn't counted by `strlen()`. And since array indexes start at `0`, when you write the first character to `strlen(argv)+1`, you're writing after the 0 byte, so the addition never shows up.

It should be:

```
size_t len = strlen(argv);
nomeFile = (char*)malloc( (4+len)*sizeof(char) );
strcpy(nomeFile, argv);
nomeFile[len] = '.';
nomeFile[len+1] = 'g';
nomeFile[len+2] = 'f';
nomeFile[len+3] = 0;
```

It's also a bad idea to keep calling `strlen(argv)`. This has to search the string for the 0 byte every time. I've called it once and saved it in a variable. It also makes the code more readable, IMHO.

You could also use `strcat()`:

```
strcpy(nomeFile, argv);
strcat(nomeFile, ".gf");
```

Answer (score 0):

nomeFile is initiated as a char array. The index of the char array starts at 0, thus strlen()+1 adds your first char after the terminating nul char.

```
nomeFile[strlen(argv)] = '.';
nomeFile[strlen(argv)+1] = 'g';
nomeFile[strlen(argv)+2] = 'f';
```

And you need a new terminating nul char, thus, you need to increase the buffer by one (`nomeFile = (char*)malloc( (4+strlen(argv))*sizeof(char) );`) and add a nul char at the end

```
nomeFile[strlen(argv)+3] = 0;
```